# How do we interface barcode reader and raspberry pi

Tags: raspbian, database

I am developing a project to use a barcode reader to read information from id and put them into a database and i have used the pi for simple projects i have never done such a project any help please? with all the procedure? I am using Raspberry pi 2 model b and idtech barcode reader here is it https://www.barcodesinc.com/idtech/part-wcr3237-700us.htm#specs

Comment: what have you tried so far? what problems do you have? this site here is to help out with problems but it's not to deliver some sort of "homework" solution

Answer (score 3):

If you look at the specs for the device you linked, it says that it is a "USB-Keyboard Interface" device. This means it looks, to the computer, like a keyboard. Therefore, you can write your project to receive info from a keyboard and place it into the database.

Comment: There is an awkward side effect to devices that emulate a keyboard - it means that their output goes to whatever is currently expecting keyboard input, which may not be the thing you want it to be.  There are ways to get exclusive use of an input device - I'm currently experiment with one that I want to read RFID tags to unlock the front door to my house - but the output I'm getting from it when my application is running and has grabbed the device for its own purposed is, I think, emulated raw keyboard scan codes NOT a series of digits.  I suspect I will have to *cook* the data somewhat...